# how to allow android to access/modify a remote database

Tags: android, sql-server, database

I'm running a .net aspx application. I'll need my android app to access and modify/insert information into the ms sql database. is there any api ? thank you

Comment: You can't connect directly to a remote database in android

Comment: Falmarri is wrong.  Of course you can - it's just a matter of talking whatever remote access protocol the remote database understands (or giving it a remote access capability if it doesn't already have one)  Since the android device gives you several full-featured programming languages to choose from and a good network sockets stack, that's no problem at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any special API. Just use Android's [HTTPCLIENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) and perform `POST` and `GET` operations against your ASP.NET application to access and modify SQLServer's data.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of but you could write a server app on the client machine (or any machine with access to the DB) and connect to that via your android app and send commands.

Comment: explain? O.o any more detailed like a tutorial?

Comment: Lots of subject to research here, Try learning on how to host a HTTP Server, or a TCP Socket Server, then you can send commands, and receive the answers through your server. If you choose to use HTTP Server then you can use HTTPCLIENT Class as suggested by Pablo to connect.